# How can I get Windows 10 to identify bluetooth devices

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I'd like to connect my laptop (Acer spin3) to my bluetooth headphones (a cheap pair of Totu's).   When I turn on bluetooth and go to 'add a device' I get a list of about 30 unknown devices (apartment living! I only have 3 devices myself used with other systems).

[image: Add a device dialog]

The headphones identify as TOTO and pair no problem with my phone (which only shows 6 bluetooth devices in the settings listed by name or by a hex code).

My drivers are updated (in fact are newer version than what is on the ACER's website).

How can I get my laptop to correctly identify bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone I have found a workaround.

Running nirsoft's BluetoothView and having the Windows 10 connect device dialog open at the same time and then pairing my bluetooth headset did the trick. I just right clicked on the nirsoft Bluetoothview listing that was most recently detected after starting the pairing process and selected the 'try to connect' right click menu item. It then resolved the description for the headset and when I went to the Windows 10 connect a device dialog it was listed with a proper description and I also connected it there.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 supports Bluetooth 4.1 and the lower versions, while your phone may not support so many Bluetooth versions.

Meanwhile, the maximum range for Windows 10 device could be about 60m, but for phone, the maximum range cannot reach 60m, exceeds 10m, symbol will become very slight.

On my Windows 10 Pro machine, there are also many unknown Bluetooth devices, I never care them, just matching my Bluetooth headset is enough.

Try to run Bluetooth troubleshooter, uninstall current Bluetooth device from device manager and delete driver, install driver from manufacturer, keep system is up to date, that’s all.

Comment: That's a useful explanation for the difference in devices between the phone and computer's device list size but no help at all for the problem with 95% of the devices on my computer being Unknown Device, including my headset, which makes it impossible for me to use bluetooth on my laptop.